# Substring in DataWeave up to the occurrence of a character

Tags: regex, mule, substring, dataweave

In DataWeave, how would I substring an input value such that the output is everything up to the occurrence of a character? My input value is something like `ABCD_123` and I need to take everything up to the underscore, so my output would be `ABCD`. The regex that achieves this is `/[^_]*/`, but I can't find a way to implement this using DataWeave. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I guess you can use `%function words(name) name splitBy "_"` and then `using (parts =  words($variable)){
  myVar: parts[0], ...` (see [this reference](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-reference-documentation)).

Comment: Thank you for your comment @WiktorStribiżew, I've now added an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @WiktorStribiżew's comment, the way I solved this was by declaring a function:

`%function split(text) text splitBy "_"`

And then in my DW mapping, I take the value as:

`OUTPUT: split(payload.INPUT)[0]`